# How to get last value (integer/decimal) from file in Perl?

Tags: perl, grep

I have few files like mem1.txt, mem2.txt and mem3.txt like below in this case and I want to extract last integer or decimal from it through Perl on Linux machine.

```
$ cat mem1.txt
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "rbbn_pod_container_resource_limits",
          "cluster": "blr-ocp1",
          "container_name": "slb-container",
          "k8s_pod_name": "sksbx2756x3-slb-57cf86b5-89lx9",
          "service_name": "container-system-metrics"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1676562016.975,
            "8589934592"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
$ cat mem2.txt
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "rbbn_pod_container_resource_limits",
          "cluster": "blr-ocp1",
          "container_name": "slb-container",
          "k8s_pod_name": "sksbx2756x3-slb-57cf86b5-89lx9",
          "service_name": "container-system-metrics"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1676562016.975,
            "1.02"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
$ cat mem3.txt
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "rbbn_pod_container_resource_limits",
          "cluster": "blr-ocp1",
          "container_name": "slb-container",
          "k8s_pod_name": "sksbx2756x3-slb-57cf86b5-89lx9",
          "service_name": "container-system-metrics"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1676562016.975,
            "4"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would be expecting the out as below (values without quotes)

```
8589934592
1.02
4
```

It will be helpful if I can extract all these data type through single command...

Comment: Please post vaild JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
$ jq -r '.data.result|.[0].values|.[0]|.[1]' file{1,2,3}.json 
8589934592
1.02
4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron):

```
$ ls -1 file{1,2,3}.json;
file1.json
file2.json
file3.json

$ gron file1.json 
json = {};
json.data = {};
json.data.result = [];
json.data.result[0] = {};
json.data.result[0].metric = {};
json.data.result[0].metric.__name__ = "rbbn_pod_container_resource_limits";
json.data.result[0].metric.cluster = "blr-ocp1";
json.data.result[0].metric.container_name = "slb-container";
json.data.result[0].metric.k8s_pod_name = "sksbx2756x3-slb-57cf86b5-89lx9";
json.data.result[0].metric.service_name = "container-system-metrics";
json.data.result[0].values = [];
json.data.result[0].values[0] = [];
json.data.result[0].values[0][0] = 1676562016.975;
json.data.result[0].values[0][1] = "8589934592";
json.data.resultType = "matrix";
json.status = "success";

$ for j in file{1,2,3}.json; do
    gron "$j" |
    awk -F' = ' '
        $1 == "json.data.result[0].values[0][1]"{
            gsub(/\042|;/, "")
            print $2
        }
     '
done
```

##### Output

```
8589934592
1.02
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) as requested, using [`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) [c](/questions/tagged/c) parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

use File::Slurp;
use JSON::XS;

my @results;

sub fetch_value {
    my $file = shift;
    my $obj = read_file($file);
    $obj = decode_json $obj;
    return $obj->{"data"}{"result"}[0]{"values"}[0][1];
}

foreach my $i (1..3) {
    push @results, fetch_value("file${i}.json");
}

say join "\n", @results;
```

##### Output

```
8589934592
1.02
4
```

Comment: Wow, this works exactly as I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Not a `perl` solution, but a good example of how succinct [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is at extracting data from json files.

```
$ jq '.data.result[].values[] | last | tonumber'  mem*.txt
8589934592
1.02
4
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Parsrs' parsrj.sh](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs):

```bash
for x in mem[123].txt; do
   # Convert JSON to recode-oriented format
   # Absense of -t option outputs every value as a string
   # e.g. [0,"1",null,"\"2\""]
   # => $[0] 0<0x0a>$[1] 1<0x0a>$[2] null<0x0a>$[3] \"2\"
   # if -t was there then every string is quoted and others are not
   # e.g. [0,"1",null,"\"2\""]
   # => $[0] 0<0x0a>$[1] "1"<0x0a>$[2] null<0x0a>$[3] "\"2\""
   # The -e option escapes impolite characters " ", ".", "\t"(<0x09>), "[", "]"
   # in key to make the output unambiguous
   parsrj.sh -e "$x" |

   # Get last line
   tail -n 1 |

   # Since every output of parsrj.sh shall be formatted to:
   # <key> <0x20> <value>
   # separate a line with <0x20>, then get 2nd to last columns
   # which is equivalent to <value>
   cut -d ' ' -f 2-
done
```